# Obiee agents sending delivery content in different formats for different uses

Tags: oracle, agent, obiee

One interesting thing has occured lately in our delivery files. We had an agent that had a task to send content of Obiee analysis to several destinations (in this case email addresses) on a daily basis in xls format.

However, when emails were received, we noticed that to one recepient content is delivered in .xls format, but for others in .dat format.

We couldn't find any file or menu in obiee settings where this paramater may be modified. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one. OA sends out a payload and then your mail server does...whatever it does. The problem will be at the mail server stage.